# Flutter app crashes on google playstore due to Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, flutter-dependencies, android-multidex

We created an basic app and pushed to store. When has been published app by google, it crashes all the time when opening application. When I check on google play console logs, i found below exception. Anybody knows that issue? I checked on web but did not find any proper solution.(shows Android 9 and 10 got error but did not try another versions.)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3341)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3595)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2147)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7811)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1068)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity (AppComponentFactory.java:95)
  at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity (CoreComponentFactory.java)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity (Instrumentation.java:1251)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3329)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3595)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2147)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7811)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1068)
```

Flutter Doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.19.0-4.3.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.900], locale tr-TR)
    • Flutter version 1.19.0-4.3.pre at C:\erkan\flutter
    • Framework revision 8fe7655ed2 (10 days ago), 2020-07-01 14:31:18 -0700
    • Engine revision 9a28c3bcf4
    • Dart version 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-14.1.beta)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\erkan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit
      https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[!] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3)
    • IntelliJ at C:\erkan\progs\ideaIC-2019.3.1.win
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.5731

[√] VS Code (version 1.43.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\erkan\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.9.1

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Web Server • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
    • Chrome     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 83.0.4103.116
```

app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.coderals.recycleearth"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: I've got the same issue, did you manage to figure out what caused the issue ?

Comment: Yes solved the issue. I’ve changed my app name on xml file but did not change the actually path(folder names)